# How would you adblock using Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, adblock

I'm slowly building a [web browser](http://github.com/regomodo/qtBrowser/tree/master) in PyQt4 and like the speed i'm getting out of it. However, I want to combine easylist.txt with it. I believe adblock uses this to block http requests by the browser.

How would you go about it using python/PyQt4?

[edit1] Ok. I think i've setup Privoxy. I haven't setup any additional filters and it seems to work. The PyQt4 i've tried to use looks like this

```
self.proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"  
self.proxyPORT= 8118  
proxy = QNetworkProxy()  
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)  
proxy.setHostName(self.proxyIP)  
proxy.setPort(self.proxyPORT)  
QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
```

However, this does absolutely nothing and I cannot make sense of the docs and can not find any examples.

[edit2] I've just noticed that i'f I change self.proxyIP to my actual local IP rather than 127.0.0.1 the page doesn't load. So something is happening.

Comment: Do you have control from Python over what HTTP requests is done? If not, it's going to be tricky. If yes, then it's trivial.

Sooo.... strange question I think.

Comment: I've just had a look at http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qhttp.html and I think it may be possible. May be just a matter of figuring out how.

Comment: What are you asking? How to identify ads? If so, I'd grab a copy of the EasyList subscription from AdBlock Plus and use that.

Comment: How to implement the easylist rules in Python to find ads and block/prevent certain http requests based on the easylist rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd try giving an answer for anyone who happens to stumble upon it. You could create a subclass of QNetworkAccessManager and combine it with https://github.com/atereshkin/abpy. Something kind of like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager
from abpy import Filter
adblockFilter = Filter(file("easylist.txt"))
class MyNetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def createRequest(self, op, request, device=None):
        url = request.url().toString()
        doFilter = adblockFilter.match(url)
        if doFilter:
            return QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self, self.GetOperation, QNetworkRequest(QUrl()))
        else:
            QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self, op, request, device)
myNetworkAccessManager = MyNetworkAccessManager()
```

After that, set the following on all your QWebView instances, or make a subclass of QWebView:

```
QWebView.page().setNetworkAccessManager(myNetworkAccessManager)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Is this question about web filtering?

Then try use some of external web-proxy, for sample Privoxy  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privoxy).

Comment: Yeah, web filtering. If privoxy does what I need that would save effort. Would it be more efficient to prevent requests rather than block them?

Comment: Yes, definitely. If you block it, you still load the resource (image, script, whatever); the request is still made. If you prevent the request, no loading happens.

Comment: Prevent... block..

What the difference here? 
It may be difficult to rewrite HTML code for blocking G00gle Ads (for sample) but easy to catch and block requests by URL.

Answer (score 0):

The easylist.txt file is simply plain text, as demonstrated here: http://adblockplus.mozdev.org/easylist/easylist.txt

lines beginning with [ and also ! appear to be comments, so it is simply a case of sorting through the file, and searching for the correct things in the url/request depending upon the starting character of the line in the easylist.txt file.

Comment: I already knew what was in the list. I'm just trying to see if it's possible to block requests or prevent them from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Privoxy is solid.  If you want it to be completely API based though, check out the [BrightCloud web filtering API](http://bcws.brightcloud.com) as well.