# PyQt5/PySide2 AdBlock

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, qwebengineview

I am trying to create a floating browser for youtube and other media.
I found some old examples of adblock like for PyQt4/PySide but now they are deprecated and I can't translate them to PySide2 QWebEngineView.

Any ideas of how insert the adblock inside a QWebEngineView?

Older version link [How would you adblock using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083170/how-would-you-adblock-using-python)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @eyllanesc, added the link for the older version.
I am reading the docs but nothing so far, it seems the methods were ripped off. I believe they changed the names, the modules and how to implement :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter urls, a QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor must be implemented, and if you want to block the url you must call the block (True) function to the QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo. For filtering I will use the [adblockparser](https://pypi.org/project/adblockparser/) library and the [easylist.txt](https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineCore, QtWebEngineWidgets
from adblockparser import AdblockRules

with open("easylist.txt") as f:
    raw_rules = f.readlines()
    rules = AdblockRules(raw_rules)

class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        url = info.requestUrl().toString()
        if rules.should_block(url):
            print("block::::::::::::::::::::::", url)
            info.block(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()
    QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile().setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks man :D
Any tips for looking the PyQT5/PySide2 docs or reference sites?

Comment: I still can see youtube ads :(

Comment: This is unfortunately causing my browser to be slow, because of the file size probably.  Is there a way to speed this up, maybe use a smaller file?